# Bootstrap with jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

I must use [this plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) on my website with bootstrap but it doesn't work with bootstrap.

anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

or anyone has any alternative way ?

**UPDATE:**

I solved this problem my self.

You must add this peace of code in your script :

```
 $('.mCustomScrollBox').addClass('col-xs-12');
```

and you must add these peace of css code in your style sheet:

```
    #posts{
        overflow: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

ps: the #posts is the scroll able div that you want to has custom scroll.

Comment: I had couple issues implementing this plugin, but I did it. Add some code you did so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your concern ...
I solve it my self.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `html` into any block you created with bootstrap:

```
<div class="scroll-box">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        .... 
    </ul>
</div>
```

And call it:

```
$.each($('.scroll-box'), function () {
    $(this).mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2jSpa/)

Comment: Thank you for your concern and answer ... I solve it my self.